# How do we get a simplicial homology functor?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, axiom-of-choice, homology-cohomology, simplicial-stuff

The *$n$-th simplicial homology group* $H_n(A)$ of an abstract simplicial complex $A$ depends on the choice of an orientation for $A$ (but for different orientations, the homology groups are isomorphic!).

Does that mean that in order to get a functor $$H_n \;\colon\; \mathrm{Smp} \to \mathrm{Ab}$$ I have to choose an orientation for every possible abstract simplicial complex? If so, this will require a version of the axiom of choice for classes. Is this reasonable or is there a nicer way to get such a functor?

**Edit (after first few answers):**

Many people have proposed to include the orientation of a simplex in its definition (*oriented simplex*). This is a valid approch of course.
But I should have mentioned that I would like to use, if possible, the (minimalistic) definition of an abstract simplex, which you can find e.g. on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_simplicial_complex). Sorry for not making this clear.

Comment: I think that you need to choose a local orientation on every simplex (what if you simplicial complex is a mobius band?) One common trick to reduce the number of choices is to choose a total order on the vertices.

Comment: I can't say anything about whether or not the functor depends on choice of orientation. If the groups are isomorphic and there are canonical choices for these groups, then most certainly there's no need to appeal to the axiom of choice here. If you do have to choose an orientation for each complex, and there is a proper class of complexes then it is quite likely to depend on a class version of the axiom of choice. But, since I know almost nothing about that stuff, it's hard for me to say exactly.

Comment: @user126154 It is true that different orientations yield isomorphic homologies, but they do not yield the exact same chain complex, maps, etc., that are used to define homology.

Comment: @BabyDragon: Choosing a linear order for each set also requires the axiom of choice for classes, if you have a proper class of sets.

Comment: @user126154, your simplicies are ordered tuples of vertices, so this will define your boundary map. However, in some treatments, the simplicies are note ordered, which can create some awkward issues that you mention.

Comment: This a good (and subtle) question. I think the functor is only naturally defined if either the left category is that of oriented simplicial complexes (simplices are ordered tuples), or the right category is the skeleton of $\mbox{Ab}$, in which case every isomorphism class is represented by exactly one object.

Comment: Replacing $\mathbf{Ab}$ with its skeleton only solves the issue of objects being defined up to isomorphism. You still have to worry about functoriality.

Comment: @ZhenLin true. That would just push the problem to making a choice about automorphisms.

Comment: @Daniel: My experience is that often people think that pushing the problem solves it (and only after pointing that out, they realize the mistake). One of my teachers in undergrad once told us jokingly that usually a mathematician doesn't solve a problem, it pushes it to another field. Seems consistent with that sort of behavior! ;-)

Comment: Beside Zhen Lins embedding into $\mathbf{sSet}$, you could also take the barycentric subdivision of your simplicial complex, which is weakly homotopy equivalent to the original abstract simplicial complex, and has a canonical orientation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to embed the category of abstract simplicial complexes inside the category of symmetric simplicial sets (= functor $\mathbf{F}^\mathrm{op} \to \mathbf{Set}$, where $\mathbf{F}$ is the category of positive finite cardinals): this can be done by sending an abstract simplicial complex $X$ to the symmetric simplicial set $\mathrm{Hom}(\Delta^{\bullet}, X)$.

Now let $\mathbf{\Delta}$ be the category of positive finite ordinals (and monotone maps). There is an evident embedding $\mathbf{\Delta} \to \mathbf{F}$, so by restriction, every symmetric simplicial set is also a simplicial set (= functor $\mathbf{\Delta}^\mathrm{op} \to \mathbf{Set}$). It is straightforward to define a homology functor $H_* : [\mathbf{\Delta}^\mathrm{op}, \mathbf{Set}] \to \mathbf{Gr Ab}$.

Of course, what one has to show is that putting all this together recovers the traditional definition of simplicial homology for an abstract simplicial complex. Let $\Delta^n$ be the standard $n$-simplex (with its canonical ordering), let $X$ be an abstract simplicial complex, let $Y$ be the corresponding symmetric simplicial set, and choose a linear ordering of the vertices of $X$. Then the chain complexes $C_{\bullet} (X)$ and $C_{\bullet} (Y)$ are defined as follows:

- $C_{n} (X)$ is freely generated by the set of (non-degenerate) $n$-simplices of $X$, and the boundary map $C_{n} (X) \to C_{n-1} (X)$ is defined by the usual alternating sum.
- $C_{n} (Y)$ is freely generated by the set of (possibly degenerate) simplicial maps $\Delta^n \to X$, and the boundary map $C_{n} (Y) \to C_{n-1} (Y)$ is defined by the alternating sum where the numbering is induced by the canonical ordering of $\Delta^n$ (not the linear order of the vertices of $X$).

The linear ordering of the vertices of $X$ induces a chain map $C_{\bullet} (X) \to C_{\bullet} (Y)$ that sends each (non-degenerate) $n$-simplex of $X$ to the unique *order-preserving* simplicial map $\Delta^n \to X$ whose image is that $n$-simplex. I claim that the induced homomorphism $H_* (X) \to H_* (Y)$ is an isomorphism. I do not personally know an elementary proof of this, but in principle it should be possible to prove directly that $C_{\bullet} (X) \to C_{\bullet} (Y)$ is a chain homotopy equivalence.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a "simplex" as having an orientation, thus getting an easier answer.

A $k$-simplex is the convex hull of a set of $k+1$ points. But what does it mean for a set to have $k+1$ points? That there is a bijection from $\{1,2,\dots,k+1\}$. So simply define "$k$-simplex" in terms of a map $\{1,2,\dots,k+1\}\to\mathbb R^n$ and you can pick an orientation without choice.

---

Responding to the change to "abstract simplicial complex." You can still redefine an "abstract simplicial complex" to require that the underlying set is totally ordered, which gives you a workaround.

But there is clearly a problem with the usual definition of the functor without an obvious ordering.

Comment: Is a simplex is necessarily defined by a finite set in a finite dimensional real vector space? In that case there's no appeal to class versions of choice at all. There are only $2^{\aleph_0}$ finite subsets of $\Bbb{R^N}$ (I went to infinite dimensions, to accommodate all the finite dimensions at once). So the [usual] axiom of choice [for sets] would suffice here.

Comment: A simplex is finite, but a simplicial complex may not be.

Comment: I was just using the definition from Wikipedia, but whatever definition you use, you can easily *add* orientation to the definition of "simplex." @AsafKaragila

Comment: @user126154 That is an "abstract simplicial complex," according  to the Wikipedia definition, at least.

Comment: @BabyDragon I'm not concerned about the complex. If a simplex has an orientation, then a simplicial complex is made up of (oriented) simplices, so you don't have to orient them.

Comment: Yeah, I have clarified in the question now that an abstract simplicial complex itself *doesn't*, as I define it, contain any sort of orientation on its simplices.